# Написание автотестов для gui приложений

Tags: linux, windows, api, gui

господа, я не понимаю, как написать авто тесты для gui приложений, что в винде, что в линуксе.
допустим, написал я калькулятор на java
сделал ты там стандартные кнопки, в коде обозвал их plus, minus, ravno и тд.
но в системе же по факту они по другому регистрируются, и когда ты нажимаешь на кнопку, происходит вначале обращение к gui api, которое делает обращение к кнопке уже в твоем коде
и вот как на прямую обращаться к gui api для меня не понятно (как я это понимаю, возможно не правильно)
может кто ни будь объяснить, как это работает и как вообще можно обращаться к элементам gui приложений напрямую, без кликов мыши\клавиатуры?
ну или хотя бы порекомендовать литературу

Comment: а вот так оно и делается - прокликивается мышкой/клавиатурой. Да, не совсем по простому, например, пишется функция поиска координат кнопки по ее тексту.

Comment: Полно специальных тестовых фреймворков для этого. Вам и кнопки накаливают, и мышкой поездят.